# How to import component to component in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created hello component, I fetched API data in hello component checked browser http://localhost:3000/hello working fine, I want import inside of index.js component now I checking http://localhost:3000/. but data not coming what issues. could you please solve this issue please below my code

hello.js:

```
function Hello({ posts }) {
  console.log(posts)
    return (
      <>
      <ul>
         {posts.map((post) =>(
            <p>{post.name}</p>
          ))}
      </ul>
      </>
    )
  }
  
  // This function gets called at build time on server-side.
  // It won't be called on client-side, so you can even do
  // direct database queries. See the "Technical details" section.
  export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
    // You can use any data fetching library
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const posts = await res.json()
  
    // By returning { props: { posts } }, the Blog component
    // will receive `posts` as a prop at build time
    return {
      props: {
        posts,
      },
    }
  }
  
  export default Hello
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
// import Layout from "../components/layout";
// import NavBar from "../components/navbar";
import Hello from './hello'
function Index() {
  return (
    <>
        <Hello />
    </>
  )
}
export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you can only use getServerSideProps in a page component, not in an embedded component. So the solution to this is to import it in index.js and then send the data down to hello.js through props.

EDIT:
here is the code -->

hello.js

```
function Hello(props) {
    return (
      <>
      <ul>
         {props.posts.map((post) =>(
            <p>{post.name}</p>
          ))}
      </ul>
      </>
    )
  }
  
  export default Hello
```

index.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import Hello from './hello'
 function Index({posts}) {
   return (
     <>
         <Hello posts={posts}/>
     </>
   )
 }

export async function getServerSideProps() {
        const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        const posts = await res.json()

        return {
          props: {
            posts
          },
        }
      }

export default Index;
```

Comment: What props I want to send could you please solve this issue.

Comment: if it worked id appreciate if you could like my answer i need it to unlock posting question again.